# Click new view controller on button click In IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button action in which i'm trying to open view controller on condition bases, but the view controller are not opening. I have use story board identifier method to open the new view controller, i'm confused why it isn't opening. My condition is not working fine, i got null but when i got login and comes back to home screen again it again shows null.
My code is,

```
- (IBAction)History:(id)sender {

NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"pin"];
if ([savedValue length]==0) {


    NSLog(@"INNNNN");

    UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    RegisterViewController *vc = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"Register"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}else{

    UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    DetailsViewController *vc = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"detail"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

}

The story board looks like this,
[image]

Comment: your VC are embed in Navigation controllers or not

Comment: Print value of "savedValue" so you can get better idea

Comment: No no navigation controller. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Its showing null in saved value when i NSLog it. @TofaaniKaanudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your All viewcontrollers does not embed in UINavigationcontroller (Root) then use `presentViewController` for navigation.

```
- (IBAction)History:(id)sender {

NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"pin"];
  UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *topViewVC;
if ([savedValue length]==0) {

    RegisterViewController *vc = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"Register"];
     topViewVC = vc;

}else{

    DetailsViewController *vc = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"detail"];
     topViewVC = vc;

}
 [self presentViewController:topViewVC animated:true completion:nil];

}
```

**option 2**

if you want the `pushViewController` may be future purpose then dont do any changes in your code , just add `UINavigationcontroller` as root. Select your initial VC in storyboard then xcode menu --> Editor - -> Embed In --> Navigation Controller

Comment: i haven't used UINavigationcontroller  for all view controllers, but few of them used it. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Oneeb - oh then no problem bro, use any one choice, but in my suggestion better use the option 2 , for handle the navigation stack, when you need for e.g you want to present the VC in only one time then use present else use push

Comment: @Oneeb - is not clear `i got login and comes back to home screen again it again shows null.`, how do you come back

Comment: I have embedded Navigation controller but it is not going anywhere. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Oneeb - can you update the question else is this possible to attach the project

Comment: When i got login i got a pin from server which i store it in NSUserdefault, and show the pin value in my home screen to check if pin is null then it should go to login screen and if not null then it should go directly to third screen skipping the login screen, and in third screen i have home button if i click it it goes to home screen again , and if we click again that button it should again skip login screen if it is in logged in before. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Project is quite big. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Oneeb - I understand , in where you struck

Comment: I'm stuck  in two problems, first if pin value is null it should go to login screen which it isn't going when we click the button. And second is when it is login whenever we open app it should skip login screen and go to third screen. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Oneeb - ok we go for step by step, first one how will you save the pin, can you show the code

Comment: In login response i have stored pin value like this,    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                               options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                 error:nil]; . @Anbu.Karthik
          NSString *value = json[@"data"];
          NSLog(@"vvv %@",value);
          
          
          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:@"pin"];
          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Comment: what the value get in here `NSLog(@"vvv %@",value);`

Comment: I got this (null). @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Oneeb - what the result you get here `NSDictionary *json`

Comment: i got this vvv (
        {
        pin = 5583;
    }
)
. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: then is not a `NSString *value = json[@"data"];` it is `NSString *value = json[@"pin"];` and show the `NSLog(@"vvv %@",value);`

Comment: Now its coming vvv (null). The actual response is  this Data received: 


{"data":[{"pin":"5583"}]} . @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Oneeb - bro, then do like `NSString *value = json[@"data"][0][@"pin"];`  and print the value `NSLog(@"vvv %@",value)`

Comment: Yup now its coming right  vvv 5583 now whats the next step? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Oneeb - now your condition is satisfied and go to the correct VC or not bro

Comment: let me check. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Yup now its working fine, big thanks bro :) . @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Bro , i have logout button for logout i have to clear the the pin value? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Oneeb - just use `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"pin"]; thats all bro

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you missed to embed your base view controller to navigation controller. Select your initial VC in storyboard. Go to Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller. [image]

Comment: I have added the Navigation controller but it does not go there. @laxman Khanal